# MSBuild 2012 uses xaml and/or BuildTypes?

Tags: msbuild

I'm confused, so does MSBuild 2012 use xaml templates AND then it uses BuildTypes (.proj) or is it you use one vs. the other to create a build?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to TFS 2012 - It uses XAML Build Definitions to guide the workflow a build.  That Workflow definition can load and build any number of MSBuild *.proj or *.sln files

Comment: I know that, I'm asking if you can also use the old templates .proj in VS 2012 and what not.  I'm starting to see huge limitations going the xaml route.

Comment: and then I find this page talking about creating build projects so which is it, it uses xaml AND build projects or either or?  I don't get this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx

Comment: Backwards compatibility to legacy proj files is handled via a thin XAML layer that passes the correct variables on to the proj file (at least that's how TFS2010 did it).

Comment: Here's an MSDN social link referring to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/034994a1-fe56-402b-8ebe-6789ccdbf3fc/moving-from-tfs-2008-proj-build-types-to-tfs-2012-xaml